# Display time with jquery

Tags: jquery

Consider these two table:

```
<table id="prototype" style="display:none;">
<tr>
<td></td>
<td><input type="text" ></td>
<td><?php echo date("h:i:s");?></td>
<td><?php echo date("d-m-Y");?></td>
<td>
    <a href="#" class="removeRow"><img width="20px" height="20px" src="images/Remove32.PNG" title="remove" /></a></td>
</tr>
</table>
  <table id="tblGrid" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
      <th>Instraction</th>
      <th>Result</th>
      <th>Time</th>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Add</th>
    </tr>
    <?php do { ?>
      <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row_instRecordset['instName']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row_instRecordset['instValue']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row_instRecordset['instTime']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row_instRecordset['instDate']; ?></td>
        <td><a class="addRow"><img width="20px" height="20px" src="images/add_32.png"/></a></td>
      </tr>
      <?php } while ($row_instRecordset = mysql_fetch_assoc($instRecordset)); ?>
  </table>
  <a class="newOrder">Save</a>
```

I used this jQuery function to insert new row exactly after clicked row

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
        var $prototypeRow = $("#prototype").find("tr").eq(0);
    $(".addRow").click(function(){
        $prototypeRow.clone(true).insertAfter($(this).closest("tr"));
        return false;
    });
    $(".removeRow").click(function(){
        if( confirm('Remove row?') ){
            $(this).closest("tr").remove();
        }
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

This is working fine for insertion, but I encounter a problem in displaying the current time.

It displays the wrong time, and it doesn't change when I click the insertion button. It repeats the same time and doesn't "take new read".

This on third `<td>` the second `<td>` contain text input and I want to ask how can I (using jQuery) replacing this text input field with its value after clicking in save button?

Comment: Why do you keep repeating your punctuation??? It's pointless!!!

Comment: I started editing your text to make it legible but gave up after a while. Can you re-write your final paragraphs please.

Comment: Works fine for me...

http://jsfiddle.net/Tx4tz/1/

Comment: notice that time is not changed when clicking 'add row' button same time is repeat

Comment: @Tomalak sorry, am not very good in english but I'm trying my best.

Comment: @Abdulelah: I appreciate that, but you know how to use capital letters and full stops at least, I'm sure?

Comment: yes you are. the most way I learned english with is reading what native write on forums or chatting rooms (I know it gives bad writing habits) but fast learning rate :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When php script is rendered on the page it will have the static content so dont expect the date will be dynamically changed when you clone the tr element. You will have to update the td inner text/html with current date using javascript date object.

Try this

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
                var $prototypeRow = $("#prototype").find("tr").eq(0);
            $(".addRow").click(function(){
                var tds = $prototypeRow.clone(true).insertAfter($(this).closest("tr")).find("td"), dt = new Date();
                tds.eq(1).find("input").val("textInputGoesHere");
                tds.eq(2).html(dt.getHours() + ":" + dt.getMinutes() + ":" + dt.getSeconds());
                tds.eq(3).html(dt.getDate() + ":" + (parseInt(dt.getMonth())+1) + ":" + dt.getFullYear());
                return false;
            });
            $(".removeRow").click(function(){
                if( confirm('Remove row?') ){
                    $(this).closest("tr").remove();
                }
                return false;
            });

$('#save').click(function () { 
      $("#tblGrid input").each(function(){
         $(this).replaceWith("<p>" + $(this).val() + "</p>");
      });
});
        });
        </script>
```

Comment: yes this worked with time but gives wrong month in date td 13-61-2011

Comment: and how I can replacing the text input with it's value after clicking save button ???

Comment: Check my edited answer, pass the input text in the val method.

Comment: I hardcoded "textInputGoesHere" to show you were you can pass the input value. You need to set it to the correct value you need.

Comment: I give save button an id "save" and below it I wrote this <script>$('#save').click(function () {
  tds.find("input").replaceWith( "<p>" + $("input").val() + "</p>" );
});</script>

Comment: how will it work? tds is not defined in save click handler. What is it acutally you want?

Comment: I want just to replace Input box with what written inside it

Comment: Thank you very much ShankarSangoli